# Azure App Insight query to see the DB connection and errors

Tags: sql, azure, azure-devops, azure-application-insights

I have to do the monitoring and alerting if there is any failure related to SQL DB. I have to see the logs for the same in the azure app insights. How to query if there is any failure related to the DB?
Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Sql queries are usually tracked as dependencies so a query like

```
dependencies
| where ['type'] == "SQL"
| where success == false
```

should give you any failures:

[image]

If you want to check sql connection problems you have to inspect the `exceptions` table. For example, if the password is incorrect there will be a `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException` exception. If the connection string contains invalid keyword you will get a `System.ArgumentException` exception. Sample queries are

```
exceptions
| where ['type'] == "System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException"
| where outerMessage contains "Login failed"

exceptions
| where ['type'] == "System.ArgumentException"
| where outerMessage contains "Keyword not supported"
```

Comment: I want to see failures related to DB connection string only. Thanks!

Comment: *failures related to DB connection string only* I am not sure what you mean. If the connection string is invalid then the db operation will fail as well and it will be visible in app insights. Other than that there won't be any trace in app insights unless you explicitly track telemetry using the SDK

Comment: @shubham could you please elaborate on your comment?

Comment: While making the connection with the DB if there is any failure can we log in app insights?

Comment: @shubham *While making the connection with the DB if there is any failure can we log in app insights?* -> yes, if you handle exceptions and send them to application insights or when the exception is picked up by app insights automatically (like unhandled exceptions). see updated answer.

Comment: @shubham feel free to [accept any answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if it was of any help to you. If it isn't, feel free to ask for details.